# What types of drums in the picture below?

Tags: drums, equipment

What types of drums in the picture below? I'm wondering if they are tom drums.

Your help is a great source of inspiration for me!

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That seems like the standard set up for a drumkit these days. Bottom left is snare, top two tomtoms are mounted on kick, and floor tomtom bottom right, appropriately sitting on the floor. Just about every drumkit that's seen in bands will have a set up very similar, and it's set up for a drummer playing right-handed - but not necessarily a right-handed drummer.